# Drawing Images in 16x16 LED dot matrix

Tags: arduino, led

I'm doing an arduino activity, and I need help.

1st Image - The  given the circuit design

2nd Image - This output that I want to achieve.

3rd Image - What I got. Somehow I got this, I know its because the ***columns of the top 8x8 Led is connected and is the same with the bottom columns 8x8 led.*** (as you can see in the circuit design). Same goes with the rows.

My question is, is it possible that I can achieve the output with the given circuit design? I just want to make sure that I am not wasting my time on this activity.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Of course it is possible, however, you have not shown us how you have wired up those drivers nor how you are controlling them, so  that is all the answer you can get. Either you are not driving the serial register correctly, or you are multiplexing the data improperly .

Comment: Thank you for the answer, YEs or No is what I've needed! Thanks!

Comment: I am sure this has been done to death on oodles of websites.

Comment: Honestly, the "schematic" you gave isn't understandable. Post something clearer. The shift reg outputs go nowhere, and how come the top c1 and bottom c1 are connected together, while the top c16 is connected to the bottom **c12** ? Anyway, if you just connected all top rows with corresponding bottom rows and all top columns with the corresponding bottom colums, there is no reason both displays wouldn't show the same things. You probably just miswired the circuit, but (sorry to say it) if you wired it the same way you drew it... it had to be expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you connect all of the columns and rows together, then you would expect to get what you got as you're driving both displays with exactly the same signals.  If you want to share between the displays, pick one - share either the rows or the columns.